# Macbook pro keeps returning to login window

Tags: macbook-pro, time-machine, backup, login-screen

No matter what settings I apply within System Preferences, after a time of inactivity the login screen pops up. I'm attempting to backup to an external hard drive and create a time machine backup, but both stop once the login screen appears.

What setting am I missing that will prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it's the full login screen or is it just asking for your password?

If so, you can turn off "Require Password ______ after sleep or screen saver begins" in the "Security and Privacy" system preference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually it can be fixed by unlocking the lock on the Security & Privacy settings and unchecking or adjusting the "Log out after XX minutes of inactivity" option within the Advanced... section.